# Помогите сохранить ImageView на activity

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, android-imageview

На моей Activity есть объекты, которые создаются динамически. Мне нужно их сохранить на активности. Я попытался сделать что-то похожее с помощью Shared Preferences.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intentintegerfromList = getIntent();
    Integer value = intentintegerfromList.getIntExtra("value", 0);

    switch (value){
        case 1:
            oneFunc(R.drawable.car, 25);
            break;
        case 2:
            oneFunc(R.drawable.car2, 26);
            break;
        case 3:
            oneFunc(R.drawable.car3, 27);
            break;
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Integer isButtonPressed = sharedPref.getInt("int", 0);
    if (isButtonPressed > 0) {
        switch (isButtonPressed) {
            case 25:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.car1, 25);
                break;
            case 26:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.car2, 26);
                break;
            case 27:
                oneFunc(R.drawable.car3, 27);
                break;
        }
    }

}


private void oneFunc(int imageViewDrawableId, int preferenceValue) {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.carlistinMenu);

    ImageView imageViewinLinearLayout = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    imageViewinLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageViewinLinearLayout.setImageResource(imageViewDrawableId);
    mainLayout.addView(imageViewinLinearLayout);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Проблема в том, что при создании ImageView, появляется ещё один такой-же объект. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с тем, как я могу сделать так, чтобы ImageView сохранились при переходе с Activity на другую Acitivty, и обратно.

Comment: ImageView при создании использует контекст активити, в которой находится. Вы хотите этот View передать в другую активити и там разместить? С контекстом старой активити? Это не правильный подход. Абсолютно.

Comment: @Игорь Всего у меня две активити. В первой активити я нажимаю на определённую кнопку, и в зависимости от кнопки во вторую активити передаётся переменная (value). Во второй активити проверяется переменная с помощью switch. И в зависимости от переменной, динамически создаётся ImageView. Проблема в том, как сохранить этот ImageView во второй активити. Чтобы я переходил в совершенно другую активити, возвращался обратно, и эта ImageView там бы и оставалась